# am trying to generating grouping of numbers using sequences of numbers and slicing using for loop in R language. help me how to generate?

Tags: r

I am trying to generating grouping of numbers using sequences of numbers and slicing using a `for`-loop. My input is

```r
s1 = seq(1,285, 5)

s2 = seq(5, 285, 5)

for (k in 1:57))

 {

  print(s1:s2)

  }
```

But I am getting this output

```r
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

instead of my expected

```r
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[1] 6 7 8 9 10

[1] 11 12 13 14 15

[1] 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: Try `print(s1[k]:s2[k])` instead of `print(s1:s2)`. And you don't even need `s2`: `for (k in 1:57){ print(s1[k]:(s1[k]+4)) }` returns the same output.

Comment: And you don't even need `s1`: `for (k in seq(1,285, 5)){ print(k:(k+4)) }`. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Martin its working..

Answer (score 0):

you shoud use `k` in `for` body

```
for (k in 1:57){
  print(s1[k]:s2[k])
}
```